# how to find `toStrict :: Text -> Text` using hayoo / hoogle

Tags: haskell, hayoo, hoogle

I was trying to find the `toStrict` function of type `Data.Text.Lazy.Text -> Data.Text.Text`, but I didn't know a) what it was called, and b) exactly what the Lazy module name was.

Searching Hayoo for `Text -> Text` brings up lots of results. Is there a way to search on a signature like `*Lazy*Text -> Text`?

Searching for `Data.Text.Lazy.Text -> Text` doesn't produce any results.

How should I go about finding a function of type `(lazy) Text -> (strict) Text` using hayoo, hoogle or ...?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Hayoo nor Hoogle support that syntax. The best bet would be to search for the relevant module(s) instead, and go through the list of functions it provides.

Answer (score 0):

The search seems to work correctly [on FP Haskell Center](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=toStrict+%3A%3A+Text+-%3E+Text&env=ghc-7.4.2-stable-13.09). Perhaps the Hoogle database you tried previously didn't have the `text` documentation available.

Comment: You used the function name in the query, which he didn't know.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, I read the title and thought that was the string he'd tried searching for.

Answer (score 0):

If you type "strict text" into Hayoo the first result is `fromStrict` and the second result is `toStrict`.